# Clone data from one field to another in a data extension in marketing cloud

Tags: query, sql, automationstudio

I have a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud and I am using Automation Studio to create a querie that copy the data from one field to another.
I want to pass all the event_id data to the new field event_id_v2.
I cannot use *`UPDATE Event SET event_id_v2 = event_id;`* because it not starts with an "Select", but I am not understanding the logic then.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do:

```
SELECT 
event_id,
event_id AS event_id_v2
FROM
...
```

And use update as action in the settings